# Repeated "checking for a bsd-compatible install ..." step running ./configure in docker container with debian jessie

Tags: docker, autoconf

I am encountering problems running a ./configure script inside a debian:jesse docker container. The script works when I run it interactively on an ubuntu instance. However when I run it as part of a docker build script I just get the following

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install...
checking for a BSD-compatible install...
checking for a BSD-compatible install...
checking for a BSD-compatible install...
checking for a BSD-compatible install...
```

Repeating endlessly until the container runs out of space. Do you know what could be causing this?

Here is the docker file

```
FROM debian:jessie
MAINTAINER Michael Barton, mail@...
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget --quiet http://hku-idba.googlecode.com/files/idba-1.1.1.tar.gz -O /tmp/idba-1.1.1.tar.gz

RUN apt-get install -y gcc build-essential make sed autoconf

ADD install /usr/local/bin/
RUN /usr/local/bin/install

ADD run /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

Here is the install script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset

VERSION='1.1.1'
DIR="idba-${VERSION}"

TMP=$(mktemp -d)

cd ${TMP}
tar xzf "/tmp/${DIR}.tar.gz"
cd ${DIR}

# Required to allow for longer read lengths
sed --in-place 's/kMaxShortSequence = 128;/kMaxShortSequence = 1024;/' src/sequence/short_sequence.h

./configure
make

mv bin /usr/local/idba
```